# Error with VBA Match in Userform for editing data of table

Tags: excel, vba, match, userform, worksheet-function

I am using Match in a userform to to find a record in a table and then poluate the form with that record's data so it can be edited.  however, I cannot get past the match function, which is being used to find the row in the table for editing.
I have tried several ways but continue to get an error.

**Method 1 - Referencing the Table Column**
Errors is "Run-time Error 1004: Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class"

```
Private Sub Continue_Click()
Dim SearchRow As Integer
  SearchRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Date_Search, Sheet1.Range("Table1[Date]"), 0)
  Unload EditEntry
  NewEntry.Play_Date = Sheet1.Range("Data_Start").Offset(SearchRow, 1).Value
  NewEntry.Show
End Sub
```

**Method 2 - Referencing the exact range of the sheet**
Errors is "Run-time Error 1004: Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class"

```
Private Sub Continue_Click()
Dim SearchRow As Integer
  SearchRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Date_Search, Sheet1.Range("B4:B5"), 0)
  Unload EditEntry
  NewEntry.Play_Date = Sheet1.Range("Data_Start").Offset(SearchRow, 1).Value
  NewEntry.Show
End Sub
```

Even if I introduce as a sub procedure just to test things, I still get errors.
Errors is "Run-time Error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
Sub Testing()
Dim DateSearchTest As Date
Dim SearchRowTest As Long
    DateSearchTest = Sheet1.Range("B4").Value
    SearchRowTest = WorksheetFunction.Match(DateSearchTest, Sheet1.Range("B4:B5"), 0)
End Sub
```

I cannot figure this out for the life of me.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using the application.match function and define the SearchRowTest as variant

Comment: What is `Date_Search` here?  If the column you're trying to match against contains dates, you need to make sure the value you're trying to match is a date, not just text.

Comment: By changing to variant, I still get an issue as the results are "#N/A".  And in the userform, I cannot set as a variant.  The Date_Search is a userform combo box, and I have tried using Date_Search = Cdate(Date_Search) to convert it to a date.  It shows correctly as a date, but I cannot get the match to work.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Williams' comments allowed the coding to work.  CDate(variable) did not, but converting to a long allowed the match to work properly, so I had to use CLng(variable) as the lookup in the match formula.